# StartApp crashing android app on load

Tags: android, startapp

My android app runs fine, ads appear and work correctly etc, on the emulator and when I test it on phones using eclipse adt, but when it's downloaded from the play store it crashes immediately giving the logcat output:

```
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895): Process: com.jakebarnby.pop, PID: 17895
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895): java.lang.AssertionError
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at com.startapp.android.publish.i.b.a.bf.<init>(Unknown Source)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at com.startapp.android.publish.i.b.a.as.a(Unknown Source)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at com.startapp.android.publish.i.j.a(Unknown Source)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at com.startapp.android.publish.i.b.a.q.<init>(Unknown Source)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at com.startapp.android.publish.i.b.a.p.a(Unknown Source)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at com.startapp.android.publish.i.b.a.p.a(Unknown Source)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at com.startapp.android.publish.i.b.a.p.a(Unknown Source)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at com.startapp.android.publish.i.j.a(Unknown  Source)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at com.startapp.android.publish.i.j.a(Unknown Source)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at com.startapp.android.publish.i.j.a(Unknown Source)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at com.startapp.android.publish.i.j.a(Unknown Source)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at com.startapp.android.publish.i.j.a(Unknown   Source)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at com.startapp.android.publish.o.b(Unknown Source)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at com.startapp.android.publish.o.a(Unknown Source)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at com.startapp.android.publish.o.a(Unknown Source)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at jakebarnby.pop.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2181)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2276)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
09-28 18:50:21.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17895):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and I have no idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: are you buliding your app in android studio??

Comment: Do you have any `.idea` files in your project??

Comment: An `assert` if failing in the `startapp`'s code. Make sure you have integrated startapp's library correctly.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse ADT, no `.idea` files

Comment: I have integrated the SDK properly because the ads runs when I test the app on my phone, unless it has something to do with proguard?

Comment: Make sure you followed the obfuscation part of the integration manual: https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/Android-InApp-Documentation#obfuscation-optional

Answer (score 3):

Does your proguard enabled? If it is, you have to add obfustication code of startapp. It is written their documentation. [Here](https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/Android-InApp-Documentation) is the link. And codes are copied from there.

```
-keep class com.startapp.** {
      *;
}

-keepattributes Exceptions, InnerClasses, Signature, Deprecated, SourceFile,
LineNumberTable, *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod
-dontwarn android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
-dontwarn com.startapp.**
```